# what happened to kwin-wayland-backend-hwcomposer?

Tags: package-management

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/armhf/kwin-wayland-backend-hwcomposer says it was "Removed from disk on 2018-01-22". Is there a reason why?

Comment: "Obsolete" is mentioned as the reason.

Comment: @DKBose ok, but why is it "obsolete"? the hwcomposer backend is still maintained by kwin